# Can variables be passed through jquery hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseevent, jquery-hover

I have a jquery that works by passing variables through the .hover function. I have a series of images that I would like to change if the mouse hovered over them. I could just write something like:

```
$("p").hover(function(){
  $("p").css("background-color","yellow");
  },function(){
  $("p").css("background-color","pink");
});
```

For each image/div or whatever but this seems more time consuming. I tried using this short hand version which I wrote but nothing happens.

```
function acc(size,tog){e
    if(tog){
        $('#' + size + '_text').attr('src','assessts/icons/text_' + size + '_active.png');
        if(current_acc != size){
            $('#' + current_acc + '_text').attr('src','assessts/icons/text_' + current_acc + '.png');
        }
    }else{
        $('#' + size + '_text').attr('src','assessts/icons/text_' + size + '.png');
        if(current_acc != size){
            $('#' + current_acc + '_text').attr('src','assessts/icons/text_' + current_acc + '_active.png');
        }
    }
}
$(function(){
    $('#small_text').hover(acc('small',true),acc('small',false));
    $('#med_text').hover(acc('small',true),acc('small',false));
    $('#large_text').hover(acc('small',true),acc('small',false));
});
```

There are no error in the console log and the images don't change but if I change

> $('#small_text').hover(acc('small',true),acc('small',false));
>   to

```
$('#small_text').hover(acc,acc);
```

The images don't change but that is because the value of 'size' is unidentified.
But is there a way of using what I have wrote instead of having to set the same function for each image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hove takes `Function` objects so you `acc` function should return such an object, try the following

```
function acc(size,tog){
  return function () {
    if(tog){
      $('#' + size + '_text').attr('src','assessts/icons/text_' + size + '_active.png');
      if(current_acc != size){
        $('#' + current_acc + '_text').attr('src','assessts/icons/text_' + current_acc + '.png');
      }
    }else{
      $('#' + size + '_text').attr('src','assessts/icons/text_' + size + '.png');
      if(current_acc != size){
        $('#' + current_acc + '_text').attr('src','assessts/icons/text_' + current_acc + '_active.png');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of posting this kind of answer. But if I did, I would put the `if()` outside `return function()`. This creates an additional closure, but it has to do less work every time it's called.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was trying to do, could you explain how adding the return function works. Its not something I have come across before being a designer not a preogramer

Comment: @PaulLedger, `Function` objects are objects that can be called. The `$.hover()` function look for the hover event to be fired and then calls whatever `Function` objects were passed to it. The way you had it written you were not returning from `acc` anything callable (infact you were returning a boolean). i.e. `$.hover(foo())` _calls_ the function `foo()` and then `$.hover()` tries to call whatever was returned from `foo()`.

Comment: Thank you, its good to know how things work rather than coping blindly. I wont learn other wise

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to `.hover()` must be functions. You need to do:

```
$("#small_text").hover(function() {
    acc('small', true);
}, function() {
    acc('small', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The two functions in your first code block will receive a reference to the element that triggered the event in "this". For example let's assume you have a `<div class="imgList">` with image tags within then this could work for you:

```
$('div.imgList img').hover(function () {
   $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
},function () {
   $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
});
```